# count up positive integers loop

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, while-loop

This program just keeps running for a very long time and outputting nothing. I've gone wrong somewhere, anyone spot how?

I just need it to generate the even numbers between 1 and 10

```
class EvenLoop {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int i = 1;
    int limit = 10;

    while( i <limit)
    {
        if(i % 2==0)
        {
        System.out.println("i = " + i);
        i++;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: put `i++` out of the `if` loop

Comment: get the `i++` out of the `if`-block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put i++ inside while loop and outside of if condition to avoid infinite loop.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int i = 1;
    int limit = 10;

    while( i <limit)
    {
        if(i % 2==0)
        {
        System.out.println("i = " + i);
        }
    i++;  // put i++ inside while loop and outside of if
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

take your i++ out of the if statement it running infinetly because i stays 1

```
while( i <limit)
    {
        if(i % 2==0)
        {
        System.out.println("i = " + i);


        }
     i++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looping until `i` reaches a specific limit, but you only increase `i` in your loop if it is dividable by two. So it will infinitely stay at the first number that s not divisible by two, because it will never increase. You probably want your increment (`i++`) outside of your `if`.

```
while( i <limit) {
    if(i % 2 == 0) {
        System.out.println("i = " + i);
    }

    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your are incrementing 'i' in the if statement.

You start off at 1 & will never enter the if to increment i.

Answer (score 0):

There were few corrections as follows:

```
class EvenLoop {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int i = 1;
    int limit = 10;

    while (i < limit) {
      if (i % 2 == 0) {
        System.out.println("i = " + i);
      }
      i++;//outside if
    }
  }
}// missing closing bracket
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
public class EvenLoop {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int start = 1;
        int limit = 10;
        for (int i = start + start % 2; i <= limit; i += 2) {
            System.out.printf("i = %d%n", i);
        }
    }
}
```